# Memcpy from PCIe memory takes more time than memcpy to PCIe memory

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, pci-e

I am trying to do read/write data to/from a Linux PC from/to a PCIe 2.0 (2 lane) device. The memory for reading and writing are at different RAM locations in the PCIe device. Those memories are mapped in Linux PC using ioremap. My use case is to achieve 18MBytes/second read/write throughput which is obviously supported by the PCIe link. The memory at the PCIe device is uncached.

I am able to achieve the write throughput i.e when I write from Linux PC local memory to PCIe device memory using memcpy. The memcpy takes less than 1 ms for 9216 bytes of data in this case. But when I read the ioremapped PCIe memory to Linux local memory, data loss is happening. I profiled the memcpy and it takes more than 1ms, sometimes 2ms for 9216 bytes of data. I don't want to do DMA for this operation.

Any thoughts on what can be the problem in this case? How can I handle this?

Comment: Start with posting some code.

Comment: That's what you get for uncached transfers. Writes are faster because they can be buffered.

Comment: Reads on other hand guarantee that all previous writes are done on the bus. It might also affect the throughput.

Comment: @CL. Thanks for you response. Memory is uncached on the PCIe device side, not on the Linux PC side. PCIe device memory buffer is getting full at proper rate. The memcpy from the PCIe memory to cached Linux PC local memory is taking more time. I didn't get what you meant by writes are faster.

Comment: When the host writes *to* the PCIe device, it does not need to wait for the write itself to finish.

Comment: If your source, destination and byte count are 32-bit aligned, you can use `__iowrite32_copy` and `__ioread32_copy` (remembering to divide the byte count by 4) instead of `memcpy`. If your source, destination and byte count are 64-bit aligned, you can use `__iowrite64_copy` and `__ioread64_copy` (remembering to divide the byte count by 8).

Answer (score 2):

That's entirely expected, and there is nothing you can do about that.  The CPU can only issue serialized word-sized reads and writes, which have very poor throughput over the PCIe link due to protocol overheads.  Every operation has 24 or 28 byte-times worth of overhead associated with it - that's a 12 or 16 byte TLP header plus 12 byte-times of link layer overhead, and the CPU can only operate on 4 or 8 bytes at a time....which is best case 25% efficient (8/(8+24) = 25%) and at worst 12.5% efficient (4/(4+28) = 12.5%).

The protocol overhead is not the only issue, however.  Writes in PCIe are posted, so the CPU can simply issue a bunch of back-to-back writes which eventually make their way onto the bus and to the device.  On the other hand, when reading, the CPU can only issue a single read operation, wait for it to traverse the bus twice, store the result, issue another read, etc.  Since it can only operate on 8 bytes at a time, the performance is horrible due to the relatively high latency over the PCIe bus (can be on the order of microseconds for each transfer).

The solution?  Use DMA.  PCIe is specifically designed to support efficient DMA operations over the bus as devices can issue much larger read and write operations, minimum up to 128 bytes per operation.